How can I keep formatting of a Word revision when pasting it to another document?
I have a Word document with "track changes" on.   It has several revisions in it that show up in red or crossed out.   My publisher wants me to supply him with a file which has every change in it, in the format:
"the rain in France" >> should be "the rain in Spain".
So I tried to write a VBA macro that would take the revisions and do that.   I actually used ChatGPT to help and then modified it.   I came up with this:
Sub ListTrackedChangesWithContext()
Dim doc As Document
Dim changeDoc As Document
Dim rev As Revision
Dim changeCount As Long
Dim changeText As String
Dim contextText As String
Dim separator As String
Dim PageNumber As Integer
Dim LineNumber As Integer
Dim revTypeString As String
Dim OriginalText As String
 Dim RevisedText As String
 Dim Para As Paragraph

' Set the active document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

' Check if there are any revisions
If doc.Revisions.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No tracked changes found in the active document.", vbInformation, "Track Changes"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Create a new document for listing the changes
Set changeDoc = Documents.Add
changeDoc.Content.Text = "Tracked Changes Summary for Document: " & doc.Name & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

' Initialize change counter and separator
changeCount = 0
separator = String(50, "-") & vbCrLf

' Loop through each revision in the active document
For Each rev In doc.Revisions
    changeCount = changeCount + 1

    ' Get the text of the change
    changeText = rev.Range.Text

    ' Get the entire sentence containing the change
    contextText = rev.Range.Sentences(1).Text
    PageNumber = rev.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    LineNumber = rev.Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
    revTypeString = ExplainRevType(rev.Type)
    ' Append change details to the new document
    With changeDoc.Content
        .InsertAfter "Change #" & changeCount & ":" & vbCrLf
        .InsertAfter "[Page Number: " & PageNumber & "] [Line Number: " & LineNumber & "]  Type of Change: " & revTypeString & vbCrLf
        .InsertAfter "Change Details: " & changeText & vbCrLf
        .InsertAfter "Context: " & contextText & vbCrLf
        Set Para = rev.Range.Paragraphs(1)
OriginalText = Para.Range.Text
'Accept the revision to get the revised text
rev.Accept
RevisedText = Para.Range.Text

        .InsertAfter OriginalText & " > should be > " & RevisedText & vbCrLf  '!!!!!!
        .InsertAfter " *********************END *****************"
    End With
Next rev

' Display a message with the number of changes found
MsgBox changeCount & " tracked changes listed in the new document.", vbInformation, "Track Changes"

' Activate the new document
    changeDoc.Activate
   End Sub

This code can't really do the job.   First of all, it pastes all the changes in a new document without any colors - so in the example where "France" is replaced by "Spain", there are no colors, or strikeouts, to show what happened.   And it doesn't really show 'before' and 'after' either - You might get a line that looks like this:
"The rain in FranceSpain"
This doesn't matter that much in standard "track changes" mode, where you have colors that differentiate France from Spain.
Maybe my whole approach is wrong.   I could make two copies of the file, one where all revisions are accepted, and one where they are all rejected, then do use Word's 'compare documents' and thus get 'before' and 'after".   But even here, there's a problem, because Word uses the colors to differentiate between 'before' and 'after'.
Any help in solving this is appreciated.

If you send the publisher a document containing the tracked revisions, it's a trivial matter for them to see all the changes in-line in the document itself. insertions & deletions are quite obvious - or can be made so. For an alternative approach, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/133132-post2.html for tracked changes, and https://www.msofficeforums.com/135435-post6.html for comments.
